# Optimize nested for loops - Dynamic Programming

Tags: python, numpy, dynamic-programming

Hi I have a simple code snippet in which I'm finding the lengths of all common subsequences between any two given strings X and Y.

```
m = len(X)
n = len(Y)
ACS = np.zeros([m+1, n+1], dtype = int)

#Computes lengths of ACS(All common substrings)

for i in range(m+1):
    for j in range(n+1):
        if X[i - 1] == Y[j - 1]:
            ACS[i][j] = ACS[i - 1][j - 1] + 1
        else:
            ACS[i][j] = 0
```

The nested loop is simple, whenever it finds a match between two strings at index i-1 and j-1 it adds 1 at i,j index of ACS array otherwise replaces it with zero.

My question is can it be done faster using numpy's mathematical functions?

Comment: if you're using a specific algorithm, mention that too

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already populating an Array of size `m*n`, it needs a minimum of `m*n` operations. Your loop also runs in `O(m*n)`. So no more optimization is possible.

Comment: I think OP knows this and isn't asking about a time complexity improvement. Numpy offers vectorized methods that are optimized, not from a time complexity standpoint, but from a low-level speed standpoint (optimize the cache and memory layout, vectorize the operations, etc). The existing loops are entirely in CPython space and don't take advantage of any low-level optimizations so the question seems legitimate to me.